# Error casting Double to Int in java

Tags: java

The following code:

```
public class Test {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double d = 46.7;
        System.out.println(d.intValue());
    }
}
```

Shows compile error at `d.intValue()`. I'm really confused since I searched many questions in Stack Overflow, and according to them, `d.intValue()` should work.

Comment: I don't see any cast.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - you missed something, it is a primitive data type.

Comment: Case is important..

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel What do you mean? There is no casting in the code provided. Casting looks something like `int i = (int) 10.55`.

Comment: @Takendarkk - d is primitive, hence d.intValue() is a compile time error. If, by cast he meant that is should be cast to 'Double', then its fine. `((Double) d).intValue()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//You cannot invoke intValue() on a primitive type as double. Use the wrapper Double.
Double d = 46.7;
System.out.println(d.intValue());

//You can cast primitive types this way.
double d1 = 46.7;
System.out.println((int) d1);
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Helped me understanding diff between object and primitive tyoe. :)

Answer (score 3):

`double` is primitive, so it doesn't have any methods. `Double`, on the other hand, has an `intValue()` method.

This would work :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double d = 46.7;
    System.out.println(d.intValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`double` is primitive type. And `intValue()` is a method of `Double`. You can not invoke the method on the primitive type. If your purpose is to get the truncated `int` value, you can simply cast the type to `int`.

```
double d = 46.7;
System.out.println(new Double(d).intValue()); // will print 46
System.out.println((int)d); // type cast to `int`. will print 46
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double d = 46.7;

    System.out.println((int)d);
}
```

instead of **System.out.println(d.intValue())** use **System.out.println((int)d)**

d.intValue() can not be called on primitive type double... It can be invoked on type Double
The java.lang.Double.intValue() method returns the value of this Double not double as an int (by casting to type int).

and (int)d is explicit casting for primitive type double